# Memcached. SLAB classes and memory allocation

Tags: caching, memory-management, memcached

For example, we set **10mb** for one memcached instance. Then, we send in it **1000** **8kb** items. It means that all items store in page **slab class 2** (for ex.). 
What will happen when 1mb item come in memcached? All items will evict and page will connect to required **slab class**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few months ago, the answer was 1MB request will fail. And it will continue to fail even if all 8KB items expire. The reason is LRU is slab specific. Once memory is allocated to any slab, it cannot be reclaimed back. I have seen some mails on memcached groups suggesting some new developments in memory management. Please see http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/ReleaseNotes1411 for more details..